# Selenium doesn't recognize new opened window -Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Seems like I'm facing some sync issues in my code.
during my process, I'm clicking a button which opens a new window. 
I'm swicthing to the new window by the following code.

```html
_webdriver.SwitchTo().Window(_webdriver.WindowHandles.Last();
```

Then, I'm inserting data into fields within the next window.
problem is that sometimes the objects in the "next window" are not being found. 
I'm getting : "can't find element" error.
for me it seems like a sync problem , meaning , DOM issues. 
so I have tried using :

```html
_webdriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

and I even tried :

```css
Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

Unfortunately , seems like most of the times the problem is that selenium didn't switch to the new window(could see it when debugging).

I'll be happy to have your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wait for two windows and then set the context to the new one:

```c#
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));

// wait for 2 windows
ReadOnlyCollection<String> handles = null;
wait.Until((d) => (handles = driver.WindowHandles).Count > 1);

// set the context on the new window
driver.SwitchTo().Window(handles[handles.IndexOf(driver.CurrentWindowHandle) ^ 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure how this is done in C# but i think selenium is same you just have to use C# syntax for loop.

```
    //Switch to newly opened window (JAVA)
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
      driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
```

this is how i do in Java. you will get `driver.getWindowHandles()` same method in C# as well, if i am not wrong as this is selenium method.
hope this is helpful to you.